# R assign categorical variables to matrix

Tags: r, variables, variable-assignment

I have 5 categorical variables: age(5 levels), sex(2 levels), zone(4 levels), qmat(5 levels), and qsoc(5 levels) for a total of 1000 unique combinations.  Each unique combination has a corresponding data value (e.g. population size).  I would like to assign this data to a 1000 x 6 table where the first five columns contain the indices of age, sex, zone, qmat, qsoc and the 6th column holds the data value.

I would like to avoid using nested for loops which are inefficient in R (some of my datasets will have more than 1000 unique combinations).  I know there exist many tools in R for parallel operations (but am not familiar with them).  Is there an efficient way to perform the above variable assignment using parallel/vector operations?  Any suggestions or references would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show few lines of dataset and expected result. Perhaps `lst <- split(df, list(df$age, df$sex, df$zone, df$qmat, df$qsoc), drop=TRUE); names(lst) <- yournames;  list2env(lst, envir=.GlobalEnv)`

Comment: The usual data structure would be a data.frame. It's also common in machine learning algorithms to work on such data using matrices with integers to represent discrete levels. The question is too vague at the moment without a description of the anticipated processing to be done and an example.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand how the original data you have looks like, but assuming that you have your data on a data frame, you may want to use `aggregate()`.

```
# simulating a data frame
set.seed(1)
N = 9000
df = data.frame(pop=rnorm(N), 
                age=sample(1:5, N, replace=T), 
                sex=sample(1:2, N, replace=T)
            )

# 'aggregate' this data frame by 'age' and 'sex'
newData = aggregate(pop ~ age + sex, data=df, FUN=sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

The R function expand.grid() will solve my problem e.g.
expand.grid(list(age,sex,zone,qmat,qsoc))

Thanks for all the responses and I apologize for any possible vagueness in the wording of my question.